# java: display pictures from list

Tags: java

When I have a list that contains urls of local images, how can I display them?

Here is my code and `files` is my list that has the addresses of the pictures (local):

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        List<File> files = fc.showOpenMultipleDialog(primaryStage);

        for(File file : files) {
            System.out.println(file);
        }


    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

so basically "file" are the url (local) to my images and i want to dsiplay them

Comment: but there 's no talk about a list there...

Comment: List `ListOfUrls` is a `List<String>` how can you call the File constructor? don't you need to iterate over the list items?

Comment: Well, how do you want to display them? Just because they are stored in a list does not tell us how you are going to display them...

Comment: I want them to appear: like the <img> tag in html

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something like:

```
for(String s : ListOfURL){
    File f = new File(s) ; 
    Image image = ImageIO.read(f) ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fully working application that does what you want it to, use it as you wish!

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        fc.showOpenDialog(fc);

        File[] ListOfURL = fc.getSelectedFiles();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();

        //ScrollPane to scroll though images
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(imagePanel);

        imagePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(imagePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        //For each image URL in the list
        for (File file : ListOfURL) {
            try {
                //Get image from file
                Image image = ImageIO.read(file);

                //Create and add image label
                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                imagePanel.add(label);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Set and show frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scroller);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600, 800));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed my code do make it easier: i want to display all the "file" which means all the images because "file" are all the urls...

Comment: You have a file which has a list of URLs? - Show an example of how it's formatted...

Comment: look at my edit at the top. i return "file" that has url addresses that i want to display

Comment: Check the top of my answer, it now does as you want it too.

Comment: thank you very much but somehow it's not running. i tried to import new stuff but something is wrong. was i supposed to add what you edited to the public void start(Stage primaryStage) { or main ?

Comment: Do you know how I can create a "load"  button on a fxml file, so that when I click on that, your code is executed (which means that I can select pictures, and they appear below the "load" button...